# How do I deploy the Visual Studio Debugger to my Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windowsiot, raspberry-pi3

In previous versions, the debugger has just been there and at most, it was necessary to open the web admin interface and click the Start button to run the remote debug agent.

However, in build 14279, which is a preview build for Raspberry Pi 3, when I click the start button it says:
[image]

Of course I've followed the link, but all I can find is a rather oblique reference that "You'll have to first set up the debugger on your device". Yeah, really?

I can't find any tool in visual studio for deploying a debugger. This can't be what they mean. Has anyone successfully got remote debugging to work on a Pi 3? Can you decipher the documentation for me please?

Comment: Red herring! The message in the web interface was completely misleading and there's nothing to install. Having tried all day yesterday to get this working, powered the device down overnight and today the debugger is working. Should I delete the question or is it worth leaving here as a 'toombstone' in case someone else runs into the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what happened, but the debugger suddenly started working after I rebooted the Raspberry Pi.

I can't be sure, but my suspicion is that perhaps an auto-update was installed that enabled the debugger.